# How to hash a string without adding a trailing '\n' to it?

Tags: macos, shell, md5, zsh

I'm trying to use md5 in both python and shell (zsh on OSX).

I got this :

**In python :**

```
>>> hashlib.md5("zoo".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'd2cbe65f53da8607e64173c1a83394fe'
```

**with Zsh :**

```
$ echo "zoo" | md5
ace34ff0a763d9f382cbe6b219fcac7c
```

Since I also have :

```
>>> hashlib.md5("zoo\n".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'ace34ff0a763d9f382cbe6b219fcac7c'
```

in Python, I think that my zsh command adds a (unwanted) trailing '\n' to the string before hashing it.

Why does this happen, and how could I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go:

```
kent$  echo -n 'zoo'|md5sum
d2cbe65f53da8607e64173c1a83394fe

kent$  echo  'zoo'|md5sum 
ace34ff0a763d9f382cbe6b219fcac7c
```

Comment: So it was more an `echo` problem than a `md5` problem. I didn't know the `-n` flag, thank you for the information!

I don't have md5sum on my OS though, but it doesn't really change anything with md5.

Comment: @vmonteco I don't have md5 here.. ^_*.. I think you shouldn't let md5 command/function to handle the string, it just computes the md5 digest with **given** string. If the string contains newline or not, it is up to you: the input command

Comment: This makes sense. :) Still useful to know both solutions though! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out :

`md5` command has a `-s` flag that permits to pass an argument directly as a string.

So :

```
$ md5 -s "zoo"
MD5 ("zoo") = d2cbe65f53da8607e64173c1a83394fe
```

Pretty stupid, my bad.